# Shell script: what means/do expression - read void void VARIABLE void?

Tags: shell, ksh

Could you plese help, what means/do expression - read void void VARIABLE void? It's a ksh shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`read` can read 1 or more variables. When read is called like

```
read var1 var2 var3 var4
```

the input line is split bij the value of IFS (default a space) and puts the different words in the different vars (and all that is left in the last var).
When you only are interested in the third word you still can use `read` with some varnames you do not use. Here the author has chosen for the var name `void`, trying to make clear the value is not used. 
This example looks like the simple `cut` command.

```
VARABLE=$(echo "${somestring_with_spaces}" | cut -d" " -f3)
```